# Google Analytics Data API returns 400 invalid_scope when trying to run a report

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'd like to create a small dashboard containing some analytics data from my mobile application. I found the new Google Analytics Data API which would be perfect for that. I want to run reports in my backend PHP application, so I'm using the PHP client library: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/analyticsdata

Unfortunately I keep running against a 400 error on oauth2.
These are the steps I've done so far:

1. I've migrated my Firebase project to use a Google Analytics 4
   property
2. Followed the steps in the guide of the client library for PHP
3. Registered & enabled the API for my project
4. Add credentials:

   - Using Google Analytics Data API
   - Using web server
   - Accessing application data
   - This results in a message saying an active service account already qualifies
5. For that service account I created a new key and downloaded the .json file
6. Added the client_email field as a user to my Google Analytics property with read access
7. In my PHP projects I installed the necessary dependencies and added the credentials .json file and copied the sample code:

```
$kernel = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('kernel');
$path = $kernel->locateResource('@ApplicationBundle/Resources/config/credentials.json');

$property_id = '123456789';
$credentials_json_path = $path;

$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient(['credentials' =>
            $credentials_json_path]);

// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'activeUsers',
        ])
    ]
]);
```

This results in a 400 bad request on https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token with the following response:

```
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."}
```

Which seems weird since it's supposed to use the service account no? I think I followed all the steps from the docs. Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to include the scope you are going to use on the request. I've never used the php library, so I can't really tell how this should be done, but you might want to check the "Authentication with OAuth" session on this link https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client